# Keeping speeds of camera & mouse movements the same on drag in Unity

Tags: unity, camera, mouse

So, I am working with Unity's new input system and I have been able to set up movement on the camera so that the user drags the camera around with the middle mouse button. However, there is a parallax-y feel to the movement that I am trying to avoid. Essentially, from what I can see, the movement speeds of the camera and the mouse are not the same ([see visual](https://gfycat.com/unselfishshowyaldabratortoise)).

I have the following classes.

```
public class InputController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private InputControls inputControls; // InputControls is just the auto-generated class when you set up a new Input Action asset

    [Header("Camera Movement")]
    [SerializeField] CameraController cameraController;
    private InputAction.CallbackContext context;

    void Awake()
    {
        inputControls = new InputControls();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        inputControls.Mouse.MiddleButton.started += MiddleButton_started;
    }

    public void MiddleButton_started(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx)
    {
        context = ctx;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        bool mouseIsDown = context.performed;
        if (mouseIsDown)
        {
            Vector2 delta = inputControls.Mouse.DeltaPosition.ReadValue<Vector2>();
            cameraController.Move(delta);
        }
     }
}
```

My CameraController class is as follows:

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Vector2 minPosition;
    [SerializeField] Vector2 maxPosition;
    [SerializeField] float speed = 3;
    [SerializeField] float zPosition = -10f;
    private Camera mainCam;

    private void Start()
    {
        mainCam = GetComponent<Camera>();
    }


    public void Move(Vector2 deltaPosition, bool convertToViewportPoint = true)
    {
        if (convertToViewportPoint) deltaPosition = mainCam.ScreenToViewportPoint(deltaPosition);

        Vector3 moveTo = new Vector3(deltaPosition.x, deltaPosition.y, 0);
        Vector3 target = transform.position - moveTo * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        float clampedX = Mathf.Clamp(target.x, minPosition.x, maxPosition.x);
        float clampedY = Mathf.Clamp(target.y, minPosition.y, maxPosition.y);

        transform.position = new Vector3(clampedX, clampedY, zPosition);

    }
}
```

Please note that this is NOT a question on how to drag the camera on the mouse click. I am trying to figure out how I can avoid the the parallax-y feel to the movement (that might be coming from the fact that speed variable is constant, whereas the speed of the mouse movement is not).

I've tested it with various magnitudes (ie., the magnitudes of the delta mouse position, the current mouse position, the current mouse position subtracted from the delta mouse position, etc...) with generally the same results -- either the camera moves too fast for the mouse or vice versa.

From my limited but growing understanding of trig, magnitudes represents the speed of a vector but I CANNOT get the speed of the camera movement and the speed of the mouse movement to match up.

What I would like to happen is that when the user clicks a certain point, that point generally stays under the cursor when in movement ([kinda like this](https://gfycat.com/frighteningyawningafricanclawedfrog))

Would anyone know how I might be able to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Is your camera perspective?

Comment: Yeah but its the same result if its on Orthographic.